# UDF used in declare statement

Tags: apache-pig

I want to read a property in a pig script. Some other job produces the value for that property and writes it on hdfs.

I tried using the following script and it works.

```
%declare a com.company.Check();
x = LOAD '1' using PigStorage('^A') as (b:chararray);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE b,  $a ;
```

But when i passed a paremeter in the udf, the pigscript is failing.

```
%declare a com.comapny.Check($p);
x = LOAD '1' using PigStorage('^A') as (b:chararray);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE b,  $a ;
```

Can somebody please help me in this?

Comment: How is it failing?  Could you post the error message?

Comment: Error message: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Invalid alias: com in {b: chararray}. 
Actually i am passing a hdfs path(/a/b/c) to the pig as paremeter which is refered as 'p' in the script. The udf just read the first line there and return it.

Answer (score 1):

The use case of `%declare` is to describe one parameter in terms of other(s).
You can use `%declare` to create an alias for a custom function but this has nothing to do 
with choosing the right constructor you want to use (if you try to do so, you'll end up with
syntax errors)

Custom load functions having parameters in their constructor may be aliased with declare,
because at their declaration point (after `using`) you basically define their constructor to be used, so you can pass here the required parameters, e.g:

```
register '/path/to/my.jar';
%declare loader 'MyLoader';
A = load 'data.txt' using loader('$p') as (f1:chararray);
...
```

However, this approach doesn't work for `UDF`s because at their declaration point in the script you pass fields, tuples..etc to their `exec` method. (They are already instantiated with the default noarg constructor)

I'd recommmend you to use `DEFINE` instead. According to the [Pig docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#define-udfs):

```
Use DEFINE to specify a UDF function when:
- ...
- The constructor for the function takes string parameters
```

E.g:

```
register '/path/to/my.jar';
DEFINE a com.comapny.Check('$p');
x = LOAD '1' using PigStorage('^A') as (b:chararray);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE b,  $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me either so I decided to run shell command instead

```
%DECLARE devices_path `echo "$device_input" | sed 's/^.*devices\///'`
```

I agree that it's not a true java way of solving problems but hey it works!